# .match() doesn`t work after change the text. | JavaScript, Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, string-matching

I working on my custom block in text editor. I do it by this way.

I click input block and in text editor was added this string `<%&color=<;#F89F4C;>{{ input text here }}&%>`

[image]

Than I press to preview and see the result.

[image]

My code how I get this expression.

```
 const matches: Array<string> = this.previewText.match(/<%&(.*?)&%>/g);
```

in `matches` I get array of all string blocks and then I replace it on preview to html.

It works perfect. But if I change some text after adding of my string block row, the function

`this.previewText.match(/<%&(.*?)&%>/g);` doesn`t find any matches.

Example: I added new string block expression

[image]

On preview mode

[image]

Do it againe but with text after adding the block.

[image]

And in preview mode I see this.

[image]

The same such in text editor. Function `this.previewText.match(/<%&(.*?)&%>/g)` returns null if I change the text in text editor after adding the block string. What is the problem?

Comment: When it doesn't work, what is the value of `this.previewText`?

Comment: Also, you should post actual code and sample text; images are useless because nobody can cut/paste content.

Comment: remember that Angular "crash" if an error. Possible you forgot check if match has length or some similar. has you any error in console? (F12 to see the console in navigator)

Answer (score 0):

The broblem was in symbol "&". After the text change it was replaced to "amp". So I replace it to !